# How to show and disable video controls when a video is played in a MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to display the video controls and disable them when an video is played using **MPMoviePlayerController**. I am able to display the controls but they go off after 3 seconds and i need to tap on the screen again to see the controls again. And moreover i want to disable the controls as well. I just want the user to see the progress of the video without any control. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `controlStyle` to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` and

add `UIProgressView` to show progress

Comment: Can u please post a sample code snippet on how to show the progress of the video using UIProgressView?